# Should I use unset($_COOKIE['name']) or setcookie('name', 'myName', time() - 3600) when making a logout? PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

I was creating a log out page for my website and in the past I have always used this approach to getting rid of active cookies:

*Approach 1:*

```
setcookie('name', 'myName', time() - 3600);
```

However, a friend of mine had mentioned that he uses the `unset()` function to get rid of his cookies, like so:

*Approach 2:*

```
unset($_COOKIE['name']);
```

I have typically seen the first approach used many times and is suggested far more on SO.

So I was wondering which one is more practical to use in a user-based website? What are the advantages to using one over the other and which one more commonly provides fewer errors?

All insights are deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would use the First one!

Comment: That and because you're explicitly expiring it, so you know it's no good anymore.

Comment: Approach 2 only unsets the array element in the current running script and not the cookie per se. You need to set the cookie new and set the expire date in the past.